# PHP: Fatal error: Call to undefined method

Tags: php, mysql

i have some problems with my sban class, btw i'm really bad at oop class, but i'm trying to work my way out :)

```
class SBan {


    private $con;
    private $db;

    public function __construct( $db = MYSQL_DATABASE ) {
        $this->con = mysql_connect(MYSQL_HOSTNAME.":".MYSQL_HOSTPORT, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
        if(!$this->con)
        {
            die("CANT CONNECT MYSQL SERVER");
            return false;
        }

        $this->db = mysql_select_db($db, $this->con);
        if (!$this->db) {
            die("CANT SELECT MYSQL DB");
            return false;
        }
    }

   public function SbanUser(){

        $query = "SELECT user FROM sb_admins WHERE authid='".$_SESSION["login_steamid"]."'";

        $result = $this->Query($query);
        $item = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

        return $item['user'];
   }


}
```

Comment: you've not described what your problem is. Where does the error display, what actually is the error?

Comment: I think your error is here: `$result = $this->Query($query);` You don't have a method called `Query()`

Comment: I am pretty sure :   die("CANT SELECT MYSQL DB");
        return false;  - are mutually exclusive.  Syntax is correct, but I am one precludes the other.

Comment: Congrats on going with OO. At first it may seem odd, but fastly it will makes sense.  I am pretty sure you'll need to post more code if you want help whst is the Query method?  and what does your calling (client) code look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Query($query);
```

is undefined, as it is looking for Query method (~function) in the `SBan` class which has only two functions in it so far, `__CONSTRUCT` (this is a special case, i know) and `SBanUser`.

You want to grab the Query function from the database object passed into the CONSTRUCT so

change the above line to:

```
  $this->db->Query($query);
```

And this should now work.

edit: it's a little confusing the `db` and the `con` variable holds the database object and the database variables passed to the script. but I think your db object is in the `$db` variable.